# Is it possible to have per domain database setup with KeystoneJS/NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, keystonejs

I would like to serve several sites with the exact same codebase, but separated databases. I know how to do this with Django, but would prefer experimenting with some node.js based approach.

My preferred node based framework would be KeystoneJS.

Is it possible to have KeystoneJS/Express be configured in a way that it will use the DB selected from the domain the request is served from?
If it's something more low-level than Keystone, how would you do it with Express? (Assuming all DBs are handled with mongoose.)

Comment: Dont do that,have one app per site.

Answer (score 1):

You might find [dotenv](https://github.com/scottmotte/dotenv) helpful. I'm using it at the moment for secrets such as api keys.

just put
`require('dotenv')().load();`
at the top of your keystone.js file

For example if you have two different sites for Apples and Oranges you would have two files in your root dir called

```
.env.apples
.env.oranges
```

Inside each file you would have a line such as..

`MONGO_URI=mongodb://apple-server/projectname`

To start each server use `NODE_ENV=apples node keystone`